# Expandable RecyclerView and custom ui

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a screen that have an expandable categories
each category have items that when clicked i want it to be added to an element in the same screen like this pic[image]
and when the unselect (red one) is pressed it remove it from the list
any ideas on how to implement this or suggestion for similar components

Answer (score 0):

You may try using expanable-recycler-view from [bignerdranch](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view), to remove item from view, just

Remove item form data list when red button is pressed and
Notify adapter for change using notifyDataSetChanged()

Hope this help, thank you. :)